# How to allow i2c access by user www-data in Debian Linux?

Tags: php, linux, apache, i2c

I have a program that accesses /dev/i2c-1. When run as root it works fine. Now I must be able to run this by using a PHP script on an Apache server. The program starts and runs OK, but user www-data cannot access i2c-1. Permission Denied! As suggested, I have added www-data to the i2c group, "adduser www-data i2c", but that did not help. I am using command line Debian Linux on a single board embedded device. How can I do this while keeping at least minimal security?

```
gI2c1File = open("/dev/i2c-1", O_RDWR);
if (gI2c1File < 0) {
    file_logError("Error opening i2c-1 interface", strerror(errno));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just adding the apache user to the group is not enough; you must also confirm that the group permission on the '/dev/i2c-1' directory allow for reading and writing (or whatever task you want to perform on it.)

As root, you should perform the following command:

```
chmod g+rw /dev/i2c-1
```

This command will change the permission of this specified directory to allow for reading and writing to it by users in its group.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: you should confirm that you added apache to the correct group and that the group permissions on the directory were, indeed, set when you ran the command.

Comment: I have run "chmod 666 i2c-1" and the device is now working, but I am unsure of the security of this.

Comment: You probably don't want to give read and write access to everybody; I would use 660.

Comment: If somebody could explain exactly how to do this correctly that would be great.

Comment: the command  to add the apache user www-data to the group i2c is "sudo gpasswd -a www-data i2c"